# How can i design a  CSV file using VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my project I am creating a CSV file, but I want to change it's design. Please help me:

```
 Private Sub ExportDataToCSV()
    Dim fileName As String = "CheckRegistrationStatus_" & Format(Now, "yyyyMMddhhmms") & ".csv"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
    ' Set the response headers to fit our CSV file 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & fileName)
    Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream)
        Dim columnHeader As String = String.Empty
        For i As Integer = 0 To grd1.Columns.Count - 1
            columnHeader += grd1.Columns(i).HeaderText & IIf(i < grd1.Columns.Count - 1, ",", "").ToString()
        Next
        writer.WriteLine(columnHeader)
        'writer.WriteLine(AddCSVHeaderRow()) ' Only if you need custom headers to be added
        ' Add all the data rows 
        For Each row As GridViewRow In grd1.Rows
            writer.WriteLine(GetCSVLine(row.Cells))
        Next
    End Using
    ' End the current response. Otherwise, excel will open with the whole page inside.
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
End Sub
Private Shared Function GetCSVLine(ByVal cellsToAdd As TableCellCollection) As String
    Dim line As String = String.Empty
    Dim isFirst As Boolean = True
    For Each cell As TableCell In cellsToAdd
        If Not isFirst Then
            line += ","
        End If
        isFirst = False
        line += """" & Replace(cell.Text, "&nbsp;", "") & """"
    Next
    Return line
End Function
```

Output is being displayed as shown in the following image. But I want to make the header bold and expand the column width . Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. The CSV file format is a data-only format. It provides no way to set fonts, column widths or anything else related to styling.

In addition, I don't think your code handles all data correctly. For example, if there's a comma within the data or a double quote, special steps are required. [Here's some code I published for creating CSV files in C#](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-c).

Comment: Thank's a lot Jonathan Wood to give me suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce a formatted Excel document, either in addition to your CSV file or in place of it, you could have a look at the Excel interop libraries.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386107%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188489%28office.10%29.aspx